# Is it possible to execute mobile phone applications on computer?-Symbian OS-nokia

Tags: symbian, mobile-phones

I want to use my mobile phone application on my computer how can it be done?

Comment: Do you know if the application was developed using native Symbian OS C++, Java Micro Edition or something else?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.symbian.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian_Emulator

Comment: I want to run applications not develop them.I read the page.is there anything else I didn't see there?

Answer (score 0):

Every phone that we purchse we get a CD and data cable with that, you can connect the mobile with the data cable and install the software, you can lots of operations on that

Again it depends on the Model type of your mobile,